# Prove that $J = u([0,1]) \subset X$ isn't a retract of $X$ given that $u$ is homotopic to $v \times v$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove that $J = u([0,1]) \subset X$ isn't a retract of $X$ given that $u$ is homotopic to $v \times v$.
$u$ is continuous and closed, $u(t) = u(s) \iff t-s \in \mathbb{Z}$. Also, $u(0) = u(1) = v(0) = v(1)$.

What I want to do is lift the homotopy to its covering space and somehow get a contradiction that J is a retract using the condition $u(t) = u(s) \iff t-s \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, I am not sure if I can even lift the homotopy and I'm not sure how to formulate any of this. Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: What is $v\times v$, and what is $X$?

Comment: $X$ is just a topological space, $v \times v$ is just the concatenation of the loops (it should be $v \ast v$)

Comment: Okay, but what loop is $v$? If $v$ is nullhomotopic and $u$ constant, then $J$ is a retract

Comment: I guess you're right. Is the question still correct if $v$ is some non-nullhomotopic loop?

Comment: The second part of the question asks to prove that the boundary of the Mobius strip isn't a retract of the strip, using the first part.

Comment: Not necessarily. There are spaces in which the fundamental group has elements of order $2$, and then we can still take $u$ constant.

Comment: So apparently $X$ is closely related to the Möbius strip, and $v$ is probably the central circle?

Comment: $u$ can't be constant because of the condition. I still don't know why a homotopy class is related to a retract :(

Comment: Well, if $v\ast v$ is nullhomotopic, we _can_ take $u$ constant. The particular conditions are important.